# DirectShow.NETCF & HD2

Tags: compact-framework, directshow, htc-hd2

The getMediaTypes() of the DirectShowNETCF.Camera.Camera() return no data on an HTC HD2.

As someone any idea of the reason ?

Regards

Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is right then the platform doesn't expose the Camera as a DirectShow input.